# Impact of NetUseDel?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, smb, network-shares

I am calling [`NetUseAdd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370645(v=vs.85).aspx) to connect to a remote share on local machine (i.e. `UncServerName` is null). I am passing level 2 info (i.e. `USE_INFO_2`) with username and password to connect. Later when task is done, I am calling [`NetUseDel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370646(v=vs.85).aspx) to close the connection using `USE_LOTS_OF_FORCE` to close the connection.

My question is: Why `NetUseDel` would close the connection even if there are more than one call to `NetUseAdd` for same share and same credentials? How to control it (possibly using same *force* flag). Importantly, what if `net use` command is used to add or delete connection? I see the process (having called any of these functions) wouldn't have any control over it.

My point is there should be security or reference-counting for Add, and only when corresponding Delete calls are there, then only OS should close the connection.

Comment: Is this a programming question, or a "Why did Microsoft make this API decision?" question?  If it's the latter, then StackOverflow isn't the place for it. If it's the former... are you asking how you could implement reference counting? `NetUseAdd` sets something at the OS level, so perhaps you shouldn't force closing in that case - use `USE_NOFORCE` and accept failure.

Comment: Programming question only. Need some idea on how to ensure that deletion shouldn't close used-active-connections.

Comment: Don't use `USE_LOTS_OF_FORCE`. The answer is kind of hinted at in the question. If you want to ensure that the connection isn't closed while you're using it, just keep a file open, and never use `USE_LOTS_OF_FORCE`.